# improve the speed of the jquery based search

Tags: jquery, optimization, search, filter

I want to improve the speed of the JQuery based search that I have implemented [here](http://jsperf.com/search-jquery). This search gets extremely slow on the client machine having following specifications. `Intel Dual Core Processor 2.0 GHz` with `2 GB RAM`.

The search code is this:

```
function applyFilter(evt) {
    if (!evt) evt = e.which;

    if (evt.keyCode == 13)
        return false;

    $('table#tblTestRequest tr').css('display', 'none');
    $('table#tblTestRequest tr:first').css('display', '');
    var tbFilterVal = $('#txtFilter').val().toLowerCase();
    filter($('table#tblTestRequest tr:has(span)'), tbFilterVal);
    $('#txtFilter').focus();
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
}

function filter(selector, query) {  
    query =   $.trim(query); //trim white space
    query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|'); //add OR for regex query

    $(selector).each(function() {
        ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? $(this).css('display', 'none') : $(this).css('display', '');
    });
}
```

kindly tell me what can I do to improve the speed of the search. The user normally has to press one key and then wait for a few seconds to filter the records below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be creating a RegExp object for each object. Just create a RegExp object for your query and use it's `test` method on each object's text. This will also eliminate the need for a comparison with 0. I don't know if these optimizations will be enough, but it should help.

Essentially, you replace the lines:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
        ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? $(this).css('display', 'none') : $(this).css('display', '');
    });
```

with

```
var pat = new RegExp(query, "i");
$(selector).each(function() {
        (pat.test($(this).text()) ? $(this).css('display', '') : $(this).css('display','none');
    });
```

That is, if I didn't make a mistake since these lines are untested.

Comment: Thanks for your input that would definitely help. Will have to see what effect it does on performance?

Comment: marking it as answer, as I couldn't come up with a better solution than this one...